# Modify the IIS Web application Handler mappings permissions using PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell

I want to modify the IIS Web application Handler mappings permissions.

I did this manually like below.

Open IIS , Site/Web application, Clicked Handler Mappings, in Actions Clicked “Edit Feature Permissions “, then uncheck/Check the Script.

I want to automate this using PowerShell.

I can read the permission status using the below code.

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/handlers -name accesspolicy -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/WebApplication’
```

I tried same way to modify the permission using below code. But this is not working. Could anyone please let me know What I did wrong here.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/handlers -name accesspolicy -value "Script" -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/WebApplication’ –Force
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're very close, but you're aiming for ISAPI-dll, not individual handlers.  Here is the code for individual handlers (I'm still using ISAPI-dll as an example):

```
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/handlers/add[@name='ISAPI-dll']/@requireAccess" -Value "Execute" -PSPath "IIS:/sites/Default Web Site"
```

Here is the code to enable access for all handlers (including ISAPI-dll):

```
Set -WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/handlers/@AccessPolicy" -value "Read, Script, Execute"
```

Leave the `-PSPath` part out to do it at the server level.

Remove "Execute" to disable ISAPI-dll.

Also, [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867899.aspx) link may serve as a useful reference.